# Microsoft Edge not respecting certain pseudo elements' CSS

Tags: css, microsoft-edge

The code in question: http://jsbin.com/bisimeyija/edit?html,css,output

It works fine in Chrome / Safari / Firefox and even IE11 i believe.

**HTML**

```
<div class="img-Offset">
  <div class="img-Offset_ImageContainer">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/430x350" alt="">
  </div>

  <p class="img-Offset_Caption">Scott Preston and his wife Laura</p>
</div>

:root {
  --Theme_Primary-dark: #f98183;
}
```

**CSS**

```
.img-Offset {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;

  max-width: 520px;
  width: 100%;
}

.img-Offset::after {
  content: '';

  position: absolute;
  top: 90px;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;

  display: block;

  background-color: var(--Theme_Primary-dark);
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.img-Offset_ImageContainer {
  position: relative;

  padding-left: 90px;

  border-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
}

.img-Offset_Caption {
  margin-top: 14px;
  padding-right: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 21px;
  padding-left: 90px;

  font-weight: 500;

  color: #fff;
}
```

In Edge it looks like: [image]
It should look like: [image]

So for some reason the `border-radius` and `top` aren't working on the pseudo but everything else is.

Comment: That is due to buggy support for CSS custom property/variable in pseudo-elements: see https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/11495448/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears to be a problem relating to the use of CSS variables.  If you change the background colour to be a simple hex value, the problem goes away.

Comment: So the answer is just to not use CSS variables with IE? I would like to think there is a better way